# Rediscovering the determinant by classifying invertible linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

As a thought experiment, suppose we live in an alternative world where the progress in mathematics is identical to ours, except that so far nobody has come up with the determinant $\det: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ given by the Leibniz formula

$A \mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \left( \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}\right)$, for $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Suppose we've nevertheless already figured out that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has exactly two connected components, by noticing that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ deformation retracts to $O_n(\mathbb{R})$, and that $\pi_{0}(O(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Let us be interested in classifying $T \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ by finding an explicit map $\phi: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ sending $T$ to $\bar{0}$ if $T$ lies in the identity component, and to $\bar{1}$ otherwise.

In this hypothetical setting, by only studying the properties of $\phi$, would we be able to discover the Leibniz formula?

Will every such $\phi$ necessarily turn out to factor through $\det$ as $\phi = \alpha \circ \det$ for some $\alpha: \mathbb{R}^{\times} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ ?  If so, what will the collection of all possible $\alpha$ look like? Otherwise, what would be an example of an alternative for $\phi$?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the first question, although to the second it is yes, as $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ is commutative, so $\phi$ factors through the abelianization of $GL_n$, which is none other than $GL_n/SL_n\simeq_{\mathrm{det}} \mathbb{R}^\times$. This shows that there is only one such $\alpha$, as $\det$ is surjective.

Comment: @Max How do we see that $\phi$, as defined above, is a group homomorphism?

Comment: You can prove that the component of the identity is a normal subgroup simply from knowing that you're dealing with a topological group; and then our knowledge of $\pi_0$ tells us that the quotient has size $2$

Comment: @Max thank you so much!